# How to remove all data from an SQL Server connection to Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, sql-server-2014

I linked an excel workbook to a table on SQL Server. I did several sheets with pivot tables using those data. Now I want to distribute the Excel file with just the pivot tables. 
I deleted the connection to SQL Server, but the size of the file is still about 50MB while it should be at most 2-3 MB. I think excel embeds the data somewhere in the workbook. How can I remove all of them and have a file of reasonable dimensions?

I'm working with Excel 2010 and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Does this help at all: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot04.html ?

Comment: I went from 50MB to 45MB, it's good but I still don't understand why it is so big!